Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] Invalid OAuth response from apple.com
Apple Sign In Error
I recently had the problem that Apple Sign In didn't work in my Flutter Application. I put in my Apple ID and Password and it looked like it worked, but in the console I got the following error:
Console Output
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] Invalid OAuth response from apple.com
#0      FirebaseAuthHostApi.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:1098:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:306:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:515:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AuthService.signInWithApple (package:parkbestapp/services/auth_service.dart:73:9)
<asynchronous suspension>


The Solution I found was a single line of code which I added.
// Request credential for the currently signed in Apple account.
final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
    scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
    ],
    nonce: nonce,
);

// Create an `OAuthCredential` from the credential returned by Apple.
final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
    idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
    rawNonce: rawNonce,
    accessToken: appleCredential.authorizationCode, <-- ADDED THIS LINE
);

Also update the firebase_auth in the pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  firebase_auth: ^5.2.0


Thank you so much, @Overdose512!

@DanielGaeta No problem!

Thank you! @OverdoseB12

The same thing happened to me today after I upgraded to the latest version of Flutter (3.24.3) and Firebase Auth (5.3.1). I solved it by adding your suggested line of code. Thanks!
